# WaveInRecorder.cls causes memory leak?

Tags: vb6

In a VB6 application I use the WaveInRecorder class to record and monitor the audio input of the soundcard. With this application I record files from 1 hour. Then the recording stops, and a new recording wil start. This applications runs 24/7. When I look in the taskmanager from Windows 10, I see that the memory use every day is higher, so my conclusion is that there is a memory leak in my application.

I found out that it's happening when I call the clsRecorder.StartRecord. For a couple of hours I tryied to find where it's happening but I can't find it.

I test it on this way: every second I call clsRecorder.StartRecord and I see the memory use increases. I think there goes something wrong with 'InitWaveInWnd'.

What can cause a memory leak? All objects will be set to nothing. Can it be caused by variable? Have anybody an idee?

To start the recording I use:

```
        If Not clsRecorder.StartRecord("44100", Val(ini.Stereo) + 1) Then
           MsgBox "Unable to start monitoring!", vbExclamation
        End If
```

To stop the recording I use:

```
        clsRecorder.StopRecord
```

Download the WaveInRecorder class:

https://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=82714&d=1298433000

Comment: If you start/stop in a timed loop, by how much does the memory usage increase per recording? In other words, is it alloc'ed memory that's leaking, or objects?

Comment: Hi Jim, about 2KB. Not much, but after 1000 times is it 2MB. The objects where closed with 'nothing'. But what in de cls can causes memory leak. I think not variables...